# How to visualize an XGBoost tree from GridSearchCV output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, decision-tree

I am using `XGBRegressor` to fit the model using `gridsearchcv`. I want to visulaize the trees.

Here is the link I followed ( If duplicate) [how to plot a decision tree from gridsearchcv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61609124/how-to-plot-a-decision-tree-from-gridsearchcv)

```
xgb = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=600,silent=True, nthread=1)
folds = 5
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb, param_grid=params, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=4, verbose=3 )
model=grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Approach 1:

```
 dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model.best_estimator_, out_file=None, 
        filled=True, rounded=True, feature_names=X_train.columns)
 dot_data

 Error: NotFittedError: This XGBRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Approach 2:

```
tree.export_graphviz(best_clf, out_file='tree.dot',feature_names=X_train.columns,leaves_parallel=True)
subprocess.call(['dot', '-Tpdf', 'tree.dot', '-o' 'tree.pdf'])
```

Same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scikit-learn's `tree.export_graphviz` will not work here, because your `best_estimator_` is not a single tree, but a whole ensemble of trees.

Here is how you can do it using XGBoost's own `plot_tree` and the Boston housing data:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor, plot_tree
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

params = {'learning_rate':[0.1, 0.5], 'n_estimators':[5, 10]} # dummy, for demonstration only

xgb = XGBRegressor(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=600,silent=True, nthread=1)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb, param_grid=params, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', n_jobs=4)

grid.fit(X, y)
```

Our best estimator is:

```
grid.best_estimator_
# result (details may be different due to randomness):
XGBRegressor(base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
             colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0,
             importance_type='gain', learning_rate=0.5, max_delta_step=0,
             max_depth=3, min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=10,
             n_jobs=1, nthread=1, objective='reg:linear', random_state=0,
             reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
             silent=True, subsample=1, verbosity=1)
```

Having done that, and utilizing the answer from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323595/plot-a-single-xgboost-decision-tree) to plot, say, tree #4:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30))
plot_tree(grid.best_estimator_, num_trees=4, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Similarly, for tree #1:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30))
plot_tree(grid.best_estimator_, num_trees=1, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.. When I see the tree. I noticed that my binary variable is split like `A_flag < 0.5`  but it contains only {0, 1}. How to correct this. Any Ideas. ?

Comment: @MAC There is nothing to correct, actually; it practically means `A_flag != 1` - it's just the way the rule trees are represented internally, and it is a general issue with this kind of variables.

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments (it i literally unreadable) and do not use the comments for such follow up questions. Open a **new** question instead (you can include a link to this one, if necessary).

Comment: What does `yes, missing` means in the above regressor plot? Does that mean it satisfies the condition?

Comment: @MAC satisfies the condition, or value is missing - trees are famous for being able to handle missing values